# Cannot find "pubspec.yaml"

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, pubspec

I have cloned a flutter project from GitHub .
On running pub get I get this error every time.

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVjUq.png)

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By27y.png)

These are the screenshot of file

- [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pWqD.png)
- [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRXL8.png)
- [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Spm.png)

Please guide me to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you take a picture of your file structure? Have you checked to see if you have the pubspec.yaml file? Please provide more details to your question

Comment: I have added more information

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you have cloned this repo, it's clear that after cloning you haven't changed the name of the project and other details according to your project.

That's the reason Flutter is not able to find the pubspec.yaml file. Change the project name and other details according to what details you had given while creating the project on Android Studio for example: you have named your project mobile but in pubspec.yaml it's name is given frappe_app.

Comment: I made the change but now I am getting this new error on running pub get.

Git error. Command: `git rev-list --max-count=1 1c4e162ea4e71855856fb9e55a1545b3dae9a25d`
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: bad object 1c4e162ea4e71855856fb9e55a1545b3dae9a25d
exit code: 128

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...

Comment: I am sorry I am new to using git and github can you please guide me.
https://github.com/frappe/mobile  >> I am trying to clone this repository

Comment: You can read the documentation by GitHub and also search your problem on this site https://docs.github.com/en . Suggestion if you are new and the repo is small the download the zip file extract it and then open it on android studio it will be easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what your file structure is. But what it looks like is that your "pubspec.yaml" file is inside "test" folder, while you're running the "flutter pub get" command inside the "mobile" folder. Try moving that file from inside of "test" folder to the "mobile" folder; where your "lib", "ios", "android" folders are. Then only "flutter pub get" command will work.

Comment: It is not inside the test folder. It is already inside the test folder.